# Using != in the FizzBuzz for Javascript

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to figure out if this application of the != operator is valid for the FizzBuzz problem. Here's my code:

```
function fizzBuzz(num){
    if(num==3%0 && num!=5%0){
        return("Fizz");
     }
    else if(num==5%0 && num!=3%0){
        return("Buzz");
     } 
    else if(num==5%0 && num==3%0){
        return("FizzBuzz")
     }
    }
    else {
    return(num);
    }
```

Comment: There is no `modulu x` equality operator. You have to check `num%3 === 0` rather than `num ==3%0`. Also, look at your branches, the order of the IFs means there might be space to optimize, for example, if you check for both first you don't need the additional `!=` check.

Comment: Well, *does it give the right answer*? If no, then the code is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum! I was misinterpreting the modulu. The code works now... :)

Comment: A more clean way of doing it would be with only 2 ifs : ret="";

If(num%3==0) ret="Fizz";

If(num%5==0) ret+="Buzz";

return(ret);